# nginx ingress for k8s: how to add proxy headers to location /?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

Trying to translate the following nginx.conf to k8s ingress:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name *.mydomain.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name *.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my-webapp:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        }
    }
}
```

K8s ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      
spec:

  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.mydomin.com"
      secretName:mydomain-ssl

  rules:
    - host: "*.mydomain.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-webapp
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

The snippet is added under server instead of location / block.

Tried

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
```

Error:

> duplicate location "/".

UPDATE

---

changed annotation name to

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet:
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Applied it, no error.

```
 kubectl describe ingress

Annotations:        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet:
                      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                     From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                    ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    5m31s (x11 over 2d21h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

The event is Sync. But nginx.conf is never updated.

```
 kubectl exec ingress-nginx-controller-78cd9ffdfc-vx7ps -n ingress-nginx -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some small indentation and improper placement related issues in your manifest file, you can validate them using [validkube](https://validkube.com/). Below is the corrected manifest file along with the output

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      
spec:
 rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
     paths:
       - path: /
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: my-webapp
             port:
               number: 8080

 tls:
   - hosts: 
       - test.mydomain.com
     secretName: my-tls-secret
```

[image]

Comment: my typo. applying the YAML was ok. but the snippet was added directly under server (not location /). So nginx did not work as expected.

Comment: verify the modified nginx.conf from shelling into the nginx controller.

Comment: @eastwater can you confirm if you are using \*.mydomain.com in your manifest file. This way of representing the subdomains is not supported in the k8s Ingress and this is the reason why you are facing the issues. If you are having multiple subdomains create separate paths for each subdomain this will help you in resolving the issue.

Comment: The wildcard is working fine for ingress. The only issue is the annotations. If following https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/, the annotation is not applied. Event status: Sync.

Comment: @eastwater Can you try using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-set-headers`  annotation instead of server-snippet and location-snippet blocks. It might help you in resolving the error. This is an [example configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers/) for proxy-set-headers annotation

Comment: @eastwater is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing some issues.